# OpenGL Multisampling Lines

Tags: c++, opengl, multisampling

Is there a way to just use multisampling on just lines drawn with OpenGL and not with the entire program?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to enable anti-aliased lines with `glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH)`, plus you can also add a `glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST)`. These might get you what you want even it's not *true* multisampled drawing.

Comment: while this will anti-alias the lines, it will not multisample them. But I'm betting this is really what Matt wants.

Comment: Yeah, GL_LINE_SMOOTH is not really multisampling.

Answer (score 1):

No, unless you can draw all lines into another buffer and then combine this buffer with your main drawing.